# Rank 3 Types function example

Tags: haskell, rank-n-types

I have this Rank 3 Type function definition:

```
f3 :: ((forall a. a -> a) -> Int) -> Bool -> Bool
f3 .... = ?
```

and I am struggling to write a simple example for it. Can you help?

Comment: Ignore the first argument altogether: `f3 _ = id`.

Comment: Something slightly more complicated, possibly with all the parameters defined.

Comment: Here is the thing: `forall a. a -> a` has only one (non-diverging) member: `id`. Then, there isn't anything interesting to do with the argument in `(forall a. a -> a) -> Int`  - you already know it can only be `id`, so `(forall a. a -> a) -> Int` has to be some constant function. There is a bijection between the interesting (non-diverging) implementations of `f3` and implementations of `f3' :: Int -> Bool -> Bool`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Indeed I was not able to pass a meaningful parameter to it unless using some constant as you said. How can I change the signature to something more interesting? Replacing `Int` with a generic `b` I guess? and then eventually passing `b` as Bool and do a simple `&&` with the other `Bool` parameter right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f3 :: ((forall a. a -> a) -> Int) -> Bool -> Bool
f3 f b = (f id == 3) && b

f3_ex :: Bool
f3_ex = f3 f True where
   f :: (forall a. a -> a) -> Int
   f g = g 3
```

Changing the type to be more interesting, as mentioned in the comments:

```
f4 :: ((forall a. a -> a -> a) -> Int) -> Bool -> Bool
f4 f b = (f const == 3) && b

f4_ex :: Bool
f4_ex = f4 f True where
   f :: (forall a. a -> a -> a) -> Int
   f g = g 3 5


f5 :: ((forall a. a -> a -> a) -> Int) -> Bool -> Bool
f5 f b = f (if b then const else const id) == 42

f5_ex :: Bool
f5_ex = f5 f True where
   f :: (forall a. a -> a -> a) -> Int
   f g = g 3 5 + 39
```

Here `f` is essentially of type `(Int, Int)`, the first component given by `f const` and the other one given by `f (const id)` or equivalently `f (flip const)`.

Comment: actually how do you call `f3`, `f4` and `f5`? Which parameters you pass them?

Comment: @Randomize Added a few examples.